# Given is density function. Calculate expected values $E(X)$ and $E(Y)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, discrete-mathematics, probability-distributions

> Let $X,Y$ be two random variables with density function
>
> $$f(x,y) = \left\{\begin{matrix} \frac{1}{3}(4-x-y) \text{ , if }
> 1<x<2, \,\,\,\,\, 0<y<2\\  0 \text{ else } \end{matrix}\right.$$
>
> Calculate $E(X)$ and $E(Y)$.

I'm not sure how do it but I think we need work with integral. But I have problem with that because we have two variables $x,y$ here..

$$E(X) = \int_{(1,0)}^{(2,2)}{\Big((x,y) \cdot f(x,y)\Big)} \, d(x,y) = \int_{(1,0)}^{(2,2)}{\bigg((x,y) \cdot \Big(\frac{1}{3}(4-x-y)\Big)\bigg)} d(x,y)$$

This looks very horrible but I have no other idea how write it.. Maybe there is other way to do it without integral?

Comment: You must marginalize $f(x,y)$ to get $f_X(x)$ first and the same with $f_Y(y)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$f_{X}(x)=\int_{y=0}^{y=2}f(x,y)dy=\int_{y=0}^{y=2}{{1\over3}{(4-x-y)}}dy={2\over 3}{(3-x)}=2-{2\over 3}x$$
and similarly
$$f_Y(y)={5\over 6}-{1\over 3}y$$
Therefore

$$E(x)=\int xf_X(x)dx={13\over 9}$$
and
$$E(Y)={11\over 36}$$

Comment: Thank you! When someone ask how get $E(XY)$ I read there is rule $E(XY) = E(X) \cdot E(Y)$

In this example we just need do $\frac{13}{9} \cdot \frac{11}{36}$ to get $E(XY)$ right?

Comment: @conime not really. It is true when $X$ and $Y$ are uncorrelated. In general $E[XY] $ can be done the same way as I done in my answer with the first formula I gave, instead of $xf(x, y) $ you integrate $xyf(x, y) $.

Comment: Don't mention it!!!...........Unfortunately $f_{XY}(x,y)\ne f_{X}(x)f_{Y}(y)$ and so $E(XY)\ne E(X)E(Y)$

Comment: @MostafaAyaz I'm not quite sure if $E(Y)$ is correct like that.

$$E(Y) = \int_{0}^{2}y \cdot f_Y(y) dy = \int_{0}^{2}y \cdot \left(\frac{5}{6} - \frac{1}{3}y\right) dy = \int_{0}^{2}\left(\frac{5}{6}y - \frac{1}{3}y^2\right) dy = \left [ \frac{5}{6} \cdot \frac{1}{2}y^2 - \frac{1}{3} \cdot \frac{1}{3}y^3 \right ]_{0}^{2} = \left [ \frac{5}{12}y^2 - \frac{1}{9}y^3 \right ]_{0}^{2} = \left(\frac{5}{12} \cdot 2^2 - \frac{1}{9} \cdot 2^3\right) - \left(\frac{5}{12} \cdot 0^2 - \frac{1}{9} \cdot 0^3\right) = \frac{7}{9}$$

Or did I do a mistake here? :p

Answer (score 3):

That is not how it works.

\begin{align}
E[X]=\int^2_1\int^2_0 xf(x,y)\,dy\,dx
\end{align}
Or find $f_X(x)$ first, namely:
\begin{align}
f_X(x)=\int^2_0 f(x,y)\,dy
\end{align}
and then:
\begin{align}
E[X]=\int^2_1 xf_X(x)\,dx
\end{align}
Both work, but what you have does not. The same can be done for $E[Y]$. The integral calculations which are very easy are left for you.